# Executing an IDAPython script with arguments within IDA Pro

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I have an IDAPython script x.py which takes some arguments, which prevents me from simply using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and selecting my script.

How can I execute this script within IDA Pro and specify the arguments for the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naturally, the best way would be editing the script and have it ask the user for those parameters. IDA has quite a few ways of doing that. You could use one or several of the many `idc.Ask*` functions. Such as: `AskYN`, `AskLong`, `AskSelector`, `AskFunction`, `AskFile` and others. Sometimes when multiple input parameters are needd, it becomes inconvenient to ask for many speciif values, you could then create a full blown dialog instead.

You could create a new process using `popen` or something similar, but I can't say I recommend doing that.

If depends on how the python script you're trying to execute is implemented, but you're probably better off trying to include/import it in one pythonic way or another.

### Importing a protected module

If the script is properly written, it probably wraps any execution functionality with an `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause, protecting such cases as executing when imported. If that's the case, simply import it with an `import modulename` and then call its main/whatever.

### Importing a `sys.argv` module

If the module directly uses `sys.argv` and you cannot/would not prevent it from doing so, you can mock your `sys.argv` before importing the module. Simply doing something like the following should work:

`sys.argv = ['./script.py', 'command', 'parameter1', 'parameter2', 'optional']
import script`

### Calling `execfile` of the file

If neither of those approaches works for you, you can always directly call `execfile` and completely control the context in which the python script is executed. You should read the documentation of `execfile` and `eval` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), respectively.